# controlling an arduino with psp

Tags: serial-port, arduino, playstation-portable

I have the arduino mega and the old fat PSP. I'd like to use the PSP as a wireless controller using Serial. Does anyone has any experience with this? I tried searching online but in vain.

All I found was a couple of videos dating 2009-2010 that only shows that's doable, no how-to, no code, no tutorials, and they were speaking Spanish or Chinese so I didn't understand what they were saying.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hD5IJ0pNNs
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyCDfL_BAcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRmaFreE_tk
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hD5IJ0pNNs

Answer (score 0):

You need to program a php script in a psp it can done without hacking it

you can also use the source code provided  down

1. A simple PHP script using the PHPSerial class to
   send messages over the serial connection to the arduino from a PSP
   from the image map.

   issues & Problems

1.after changing the cycle to 3 from the PSP you cannot change to
       any other cycles. (I think the issue is how the PSP interprets
       the image map.(IE: try playing with the HTML generating the image
       map))

Source Code  [See Here...](http://pastebin.com/WijQD5eG)